# Writing from an array to a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a list and doing all the calculations on VBA however when i want to write my list to the predefined range i get nothing. The following is a an example of the code i'm using. I am not posting the actual code because it's long however this example has the same problem.

```
Option Explicit

Sub readArray()
Dim CoGrade() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim NPSeQuedan() As Variant
Dim SeQuedanRng As Range


'erases information from arrays if there was any
Erase CoGrade

Erase NPSeQuedan

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'find the last row on the data i want to read
LastRow = Range("b10000").End(xlUp).Row
'the relevant data starts on row 34
ArrayRows = LastRow - 34 + 1
'redifines the variables with the total numbers of stocks in the portfolio
ReDim CoGrade(ArrayRows, 1)
ReDim NPSeQuedan(ArrayRows, 1)

'reads each relevant number into its proper variable
CoGrade = Range(Cells(34, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))

'' test
Set SeQuedanRng = Range(Cells(34, 13), Cells(34 + ArrayRows - 1, 
13))
For a = 1 To ArrayRows
    NPSeQuedan(a, 1) = CoGrade(a, 1)
Next
SeQuedanRng.Value = NPSeQuedan
'''
end sub
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. You have numerous undeclared and apparently uninitialized variables (itself not good programming practice) together with a spreadsheet whose contents are not described. It is impossible to figure out what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks John, sorry lazy on my part not copying the whole thing and (surprise) i am not a coder myself so i must have all the bad coding habits in the world.

Comment: You don't need to copy everything -- just give a single *self-contained* sub which illustrates the problem. As a guess, the problem has something to do with how you are declaring and initializing the variables -- which is exactly what you aren't showing.

Comment: For example, it is possible that **LastRow** has the value 0, we don't know without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Ok i just edited the post, is this better?

Comment: One thing that jumps out -- you seem to be assuming that `ReDim NPSeQuedan(ArrayRows, 1)` yields a 1-based array. It is 0-based (unless you are using the awful `Option Base 1` but not telling us).

Comment: John, Frankly i didn't understand that part about the Option Base... the spreadsheet has infromation from fron rows 34 to 126 so Arrayrows=93, Lastrow =126.

Comment: `NPSeQuedan` is an array with 2 columns, with the first column empty. You are trying to assign it to a range which has only 1 column. In any event -- you should trust variant types. You don't need to specify their size or declare them as an array before assigning the values of a range to them.

Comment: I tried 'NPSeQuedan(arrayrows)' but it doesn't work either

Comment: @Frank What he means by `Base` is that all arrays start at base `0`, unless you either specify otherwise by placing `Option Base 1` (very uncommon) at the beginning of your module (outside of any subs), or declare your array as `Dim MyArr(1 To ??)`

Comment: Thanks guys both work perfectly! if i have any other issues i'll come back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution (though @SJR 's idea of using 1-dimensional arrays is good). I added various points about your original code in the comments to the code:

```
Sub readArray()
    Dim CoGrade As Variant 'Don't bother with ()
    Dim LastRow As Long 'Integer risks overflow
    Dim A As Long, ArrayRows As Long 'you use these -- so declare it
    Dim NPSeQuedan As Variant 'etc.
    Dim SeQuedanRng As Range


    'erases information from arrays if there was any
    'Erase CoGrade -- VBA is garbage collected and these have just been declared, so 100% pointless

    'Erase NPSeQuedan

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'find the last row on the data i want to read
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'why hard-wire in 10000?

    'the relevant data starts on row 34
    ArrayRows = LastRow - 34 + 1
    'redifines the variables with the total numbers of stocks in the portfolio
    'ReDim CoGrade(ArrayRows, 1) -- pointless

    ReDim NPSeQuedan(1 To ArrayRows, 1 To 1) 'this is important for what you are doing

    'reads each relevant number into its proper variable

    CoGrade = Range(Cells(34, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)).Value

    '' test
    Set SeQuedanRng = Range(Cells(34, 13), Cells(34 + ArrayRows - 1, 13))

    For A = 1 To ArrayRows
        NPSeQuedan(A, 1) = CoGrade(A, 1)
    Next

    SeQuedanRng.Value = NPSeQuedan 'works now!

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, which incorporates several of the comments made by John Coleman.

```
Sub readArray()

Dim CoGrade As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, ArrayRows as Long, a as Long
Dim NPSeQuedan() As Variant
Dim SeQuedanRng As Range

'find the last row on the data i want to read
LastRow = Range("b10000").End(xlUp).Row
'the relevant data starts on row 34
ArrayRows = LastRow - 34 + 1
'redifines the variables with the total numbers of stocks in the portfolio
ReDim NPSeQuedan(1 To ArrayRows)

'reads each relevant number into its proper variable
CoGrade = Range(Cells(34, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))
Set SeQuedanRng = Range(Cells(34, 13), Cells(34 + ArrayRows - 1, 13))

For a = 1 To ArrayRows
    NPSeQuedan(a) = CoGrade(a, 1)
Next

SeQuedanRng.Value = Application.Transpose(NPSeQuedan)

End Sub
```